# Unrecognised command in TexStudio

Tags: latex, miktex, texstudio

I have just decided to move from Overleaf to Texstudio with the MikTex distribution on Windows 11. I seem to have installed everything correctly although I am getting an annoying issue. When I was working in Overleaf I would create a package called something like `packages.sty` which I would store in the same directory as my `main.tex` file. In this file I would define custom commands and default packages which I will more or less use for all reports I am writing. When I run in Texstudio, everything compiles correctly and I get the same PDF as in Overleaf but all of the `.cwl` files from the packages I include in the `packages.sty` are not automatically loaded. This forces me to go to `Options ->  Configure TeXstudio -> Completion` and manually tick all of the packages I want to load the commands for.

This is frustrating. I would like that that all of the dependencies of this `packages.sty` are automatically loaded but I can't figure out how to to do it. Could someone explain to me how I could go about doing this or could someone perhaps tell me what the proper way of including custom commands and default packages is as I recognise that this method might not be the norm.

NOTE:
When I say I am including the packages in the `packages.sty` file, I mean I am using the command `\usepackage{blahblah}` not the `\include{blahblah}` command.